# The form's view data is expected to be an instance of MyEntity but is an instance of ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can create a form which works fine but getting errors when trying to flush data to the database:

The controller action looks like this:

```
$purchase = new Purchase();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($purchase)
            ->add('addresses', AddressType::class)
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('toBeDeliveredAt', DateType::class)
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($purchase);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

Class AddressType looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
        ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
        ->add('street', TextType::class)
        ->add('city', TextType::class)
        ->add('zipcode', TextType::class)
        ->add('country', TextType::class)
        ->add('phone', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XxxBundle\Entity\Address'
    ));
}
```

But that gives me the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   XxxBundle\Entity\Address, but is an instance of class
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error
>   by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of
>   XxxBundle\Entity\Address.

If I set the `data_class` option to null I get

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

How can I add a view transformer that transforms an instance of class ArrayCollection to an instance of Address?

Comment: A purchase can have more then one address correct?  If so then use @DOZ solution but always add at least one address to purchase so the address form is displayed.  $purchase->setAddress(new Address());

Comment: @Cerad thank you, that information also helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Addresses` is an array collection so you have to use it as an collection in your form like this :

```
$builder->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => AddressType::class
        ));
```

Instead of this :

```
$builder->add('addresses', AddressType::class)
```

In this way you embed Address Form into Purchase Form

You can see the doc about embed a collection of form [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

**Explanations (sorry for my bad English) :**

You have to think about object.

In your Purchase Entity you have a collection of Address because a Purchase object can have many address that is to say to persist Purchase object you have to give a collection of addresses.

So when you built your Purshase form, Symfony expects an array collection for addresses input. It is what I wrote above. With this, if you are in the case where you want to add a new Purchase object, when you go to view the form, to display fields corresponding to the Address, you have to do this into your form:

```
    <ul class="addresses">
            {# iterate over each existing address and render these fields #}
            {% for address in form.addresses %}
                <li>{{ form_row(address.title) }}</li>

                 //do this for all the others fields ...

            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But if you want to add many address dynamically, you have to do 2 things :

First, you have to do add `'allow_add' => true` in the form builder

```
$builder->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type'   => AddressType::class,
        'allow_add'    => true,
    ));
```

Second, the `allow_add` also makes a "prototype" variable available to you in the form html generated : this is where Javascript come in :)
To do work this, you have to write some Javascript and you can see a good example [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)

I hope that it's clearer

Comment: thanks for helping, I've tried with `->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, array( 'entry_type' => AddressType::class))` but then only the purchase form get's displayed

Comment: yes you have to add some javascript to display address form, see this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: Thanks again, now I see. I might have to re think about my Entities. I consider it's bad practice to use javascript to have a form complete in DOM. Like it showed up before, in my opinion is actually better because the form is complete without javascript. The problem is I'm not able to flush the data to the database. I don't think is good practice to solve that problem with javascript...?!